# Writing Auth data in cakephp session inside of a test case

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to write test cases for my controllers in cakephp, all controller functions requires some information from the Auth component.

So before executing the test cases, i would like to manually insert in the session the data of the logged in user and it seems that

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.User', array('id' => 1,'username' => 'myUsername',));
```

is not doing the job, i read many mark story tutorial about that but it seems that it works for cakephp 1.3..

Regards

Comment: What cakephp version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use [mock objects](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html). There is also an [excellent cakephp tutorial for 2.0](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/getting-familiar-with-phpunit-mocks) written by Mark Story that will cover this topic.

You can and should also always look at the cakephp core tests, they usually give you good examples and show you how to do things. [Here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Controller/Component/AuthComponentTest.php#L392) is the test for the AuthComponent itself.